# Parametrized query request postgresql

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I want to get data from my DB where is LocalDateTime equals to LocalDateTime in get request.

```
@Override
    public List<Timeslot> getAllAvailable(LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
        return jdbcTemplate.query("select * from timeslot where day = ?", TIMESLOT_ROW_MAPPER);
    }
```

Timeslot table code:

```
CREATE TABLE "timeslot" (
    "timeslot_id" serial,
    "day" date NOT NULL,
    "start_time" TIME NOT NULL,
    "end_time" TIME NOT NULL,
    "user_id" serial NOT NULL,
    "is_recorded" boolean,
    CONSTRAINT "timeslot_pk" PRIMARY KEY ("timeslot_id")
);
```

Controller code:

```
@GetMapping("/allAvailable")
    public List<Timeslot> getAllAvailable(@RequestParam("day") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime day) {
        return userService.allAvailable(day);
    }
```

But when I did this request result in console is: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at end of input`. How do i change sql request code to fix this error? Should I use PrepareStatement or something else?

Comment: 'localDateTime' is not being passed as an argument to `jdbcTemplate.query(...)`.  Probably need to use [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-) overloaded version.

Comment: @AndrewS I changed '?' in the request to '$1'. Output is: ```ERROR: bind message supplies 0 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 1```. LocalDateTime isn't being passed in SQL requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are storing **day** as `Date` format in the database. and in the query you are comparing **day** whose type is `Date` with `LocalDateTime` type which might be wrong. first take `Date` from `LocalDateTime` then pass as method argument. For example

```
jdbcTemplate.query("select * from timeslot where day = ?", TIMESLOT_ROW_MAPPER, localDateTime.toLocalDate());
```

Answer (score 2):

As @AndrewS mentioned, you didn't pass localDateTime value as parameter. Therefore `jdbcTemplate` doesn't bind `?` to localDateTime.

You should use overloaded method of `query` and pass `localDateTime` as the last parameter:

```java
jdbcTemplate.query("select * from timeslot where day = ?", TIMESLOT_ROW_MAPPER, localDateTime);
```